# Where is Dan Bredemann's play, "I Am Not Lewis Carroll"?

Tags: lewis-carroll, theater-play

In the 90s, Dan Bredemann showed me a copy of his one-man play, [*I Am Not Lewis Carroll*](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1989-01-22-ca-1100-story.html). It was about the inner life of the fantasy author and logician Charles Dodgson, who is better known under his pen name, Lewis Carroll. I had time during my visit to read only a few parts, and he [died in 2005](https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/heraldtribune/obituary.aspx?n=daniel-charles-bredemann&pid=86251840). I've been wanting for years to read the whole play, but have not found it in published form. Still, it's hard to believe that it has vanished altogether. Is a copy to be found anywhere, published or unpublished?

Comment: It was certainly performed; https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1989-01-27-ca-1593-story.html. Like most one-man plays, it was probably never published.

Comment: @Valorum That would be unfortunate, It was not only witty, but insightful.

Comment: If you knew him personally, a very quick google reveals that he was survived by his wife, Carol Ann Bredemann. You could write her a letter, perhaps? I would imagine that she'll have a big pile of his papers and literary paraphernalia.

Comment: Well... they weren't living together at the time, but, nothing ventured, nothing gained!

Comment: I've written the daughter asking for information...Thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was performed at least once that we know of (and presumably lots of other times, since it received a couple of critical reviews in the LA Times) but was never published as a show-script.

Notably, the vast bulk of the writing (estimated by the author) comes directly from Carroll himself.

> Bredemann, who has been assembling the piece for four years, draws on
> the author-mathematician-children’s photographer’s most famous works,
> “Alice in Wonderland” and “Alice Through the Looking Glass,” as well
> as a legendary collection of letters written by Carroll (a.k.a.
> Charles Lutwidge Dodgson, 1832-1898). “I’d like to say I read them
> all,” Bredemann said, “but there seems to be about 100,000 of them.
> And they’re hilariously funny. He’d write eight hours a day, always
> revising. He never sent out a first draft. He categorized, numbered
> and cross-filed each one so he would never repeat news. And he was not
> an outgoing person: He was shy and fussy and stammered with adults.
> But he melted with children.”
>
> The actor-writer admits that much of the piece is a leap of faith.
>
> “The words are 80% to 90% Carroll’s,” he said, “which I’ve woven
> together. The greatest compliment I’ve received is people saying they
> can’t tell which parts are mine and which are his. Doing this, I want
> to become him, convey the spirit of this strange, delightful man.
> Everybody asks me what drugs he took (to write “Alice”). Well, the
> facts just don’t support (that claim). The work came from his own
> mind, his own genius.”
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Carroll’ Through the Looking Glass](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1989-01-22-ca-1100-story.html)</sup></sub>

It's possible that the script exists in his personal papers somewhere, but he didn't lodge a copy of it with the [US Copyright Office](https://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?SAB1=lewis&BOOL1=all%20of%20these&FLD1=Title%20%28TKEY%29%20%28TKEY%29&GRP1=AND%20with%20next%20set&SAB2=Bredemann&BOOL2=as%20a%20phrase&FLD2=Name%3A%20All%20%28KNAM%29%20%28KNAM%29&PID=B_7O2Gt2k2Zw4SYC1LHXa1-716KQ&SEQ=20210912074338&CNT=25&HIST=1) or [Library of Congress](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg1=lewis&argType1=all&searchCode1=KTIL&searchType=2&combine2=and&searchArg2=carroll&argType2=all&searchCode2=KTIL&combine3=and&searchArg3=%27not%27&argType3=all&searchCode3=KTIL&year=1521-2021&fromYear=&toYear=&location=all&place=all&type=all&language=all&recCount=25).

Comment: Thank you. I think this is as close as we're going to get unless Dan Bredemann's daughter locates the play in his personal papers. She seemed interested in the possibility of publishing the play.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - Aye. If she comes up with anything, this would be perfect for a self-answer.